# Alternative to MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT function

Tags: mysql, global-variables, configuration-files, restart, group-concat

I'm retrieving the data with MySQL function called "GROUP_CONCAT()".

But when I checked the result of "GROUP_CONCAT()" function related column, it was missing some data.

When I google the record missing issue with "GROUP_CONCAT()" function, in the official MySQL site they have mentioned as,

There is a global variable called [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) and it will permit the maximum result length in bytes for the GROUP_CONCAT() function, the default value of it as 1024.

Therefore it seems I have to increase that value with following MySQL command,

`SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 1000000`;

Therefore set this value permanently, I have to edit the MySQL server related configuration file  (my.cnf or my.ini) and have to restart the server.

But unfortunately I haven't any permission to do so.

Therefore can you please help me to find out some alternative solution to fix this issue.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use `SET SESSION` instead:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

Unlike `SET GLOBAL`, `SET SESSION` does not require super privilege.

[**Reference**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-system-variables.html)

Comment: May I know whether 'group_concat_max_len' related newly set value gets reset back to it's default value (1024), if some how MySQL Server will gets restart in future?

Comment: `SET SESSION` would last for your current session.  If you want to set it long term, you should contact someone with admin rights to set it for you using `SET GLOBAL`.